# Python >>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the above mentioned error for the below code, need help to rectify it.

Code:

```
def in_range_func(self, curtemp, keys):
    if keys == []:
        return (curtemp, False)
    for k in keys:
        if (k-2) <= curtemp <= (k+2):
            return (k, True)
      return (curtemp, False)

def sort_func(self):
    for i in self.data:
        if i in self.temp_dict.keys():
            self.temp_dict[i].append(i)
        else:
            (x, success) = self.in_range_func(i, self.temp_dict.keys())
            if success:
                self.temp_dict[i].append(i)
            else:
                self.temp_dict[i] = [i]

    for x in self.temp_dict.keys():
        print x, self.temp_dict[x]
```

In the above code

```
data = [[1], [4], [34], [45.5], [70.7], [70.9]]
temp_dict = {}
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the exception you get, not just the message.

Comment: *must* `data` contain lists? Do those nested lists always contain just the one value?

Comment: Yes, `list`s are not hashable. Cast to `tuple`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "filename.py", line>>  self.temp_dict[i] = [i] 
typeError: unhashable type: 'list

Comment: Please [edit] your post....

Comment: Yes, Martjin nested lists contain one value only

Comment: @Deepak Then why use lists? If you just put in a list of integers and not a list of lists then you wouldn't have this error.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: It is only a snippet of a long code, and this list of list is extracted after several steps of reforming and extracting data

Comment: @Deepak: then just use that one integer as the key then. Lists are not hashable and cannot be used as keys. You could convert to a tuple but if there is always just the one value then `i[0]` is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use lists as keys; each element in `self.data` is a nested list with an integer in it.

You have two options:

- Convert the list to a tuple:

  ```
  self.temp_dict[tuple(i)].append(i)
  ```
- If the list only ever contains one element, use that one element as the key:

  ```
  self.temp_dict[i[0]].append(i)
  ```